# ADO.NET Entity Data Model first - generate DB Firebird .NET provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird, ado.net-entity-data-model, embedded-database

I have a problem with creating a Firebird DB from Entity Data Model (Model first, Database first all same mistake).

Setup:

- MS Visual Studio 2013 Pro
- Entity Framework 6.0.2
- FirebirdClient 4.1.0.0
- .NET4.5

I've created a Data connection to empty Firebird DB (all works fine). 
I created a blank ADO.NET Entity Data Model, created the model (3 tables with associations) and I want to create the Firebird DB from the model and it throws provider unsupported:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework;
>   however, an EF database provider compatible with version could not be
>   found for your data connection...

But I think, I use the correct one.

**App.config code:**

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbProviderServices, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the EF6 provider form Nuget:

```
install-package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-EF6
```

See http://blog.cincura.net/233426-entity-framework-6-with-firebird/

Comment: Yes, i did. I used this article as a manual and i've this problem, whitch i'm still trying to fix.

Comment: I used little bit different approach.
- install DDEX from firebird website
- install EF 6 and ADO.NET Provider for Firebird with EF 6 support from Nuget
- make data connection to embedded server with empty TEST.fdb(goes well)
- add Model (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) and create few tables
- then i wanna generate DB from model and then the error was shown to me that i'm using incompatible provider.

Don't know what next. Google says it is possible to make this but i can't see where i go wrong.

Comment: Is there any stable version alternative to use? Need use Entity Framework and Firebird. If I google, somebody were able to make it work. @ErikEJ